# Server is open SyntaxError: Unexpected token = in /home/michael/DemoApp/views/posts.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

Server is open

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token = in /home/michael/DemoApp/views/posts.ejs while compiling ejs

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get("/posts", function(req, res){
var posts = [
{title: "Once upon a time", author: "Richard"},
{title: "The Way", author: "Ikoro"},
{title: "I Love Critics", author: "Emmanuel"},
{title: "Adorable Bunny", author: "Christian"}
]
res.render("posts.ejs", {posts: posts});
});

app.listen(port, function(){
console.log("Server is open");
});

// The Codes for posts.ejs

<% for(var = i; i < posts.length; i++){ %>
<li>
    <%= posts[i].title %> - <strong><%= posts[i].author
    %></strong>
</li>
<% } %>
```

Server is open

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token = in /home/michael/DemoApp/views/posts.ejs while compiling ejs

Answer (score 0):

Please I have seen the error the fault is from me

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have `var = i` - this is the error. It should be:

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){ %>
<li>
    <%= posts[i].title %> - <strong><%= posts[i].author
    %></strong>
</li>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you Eugene I saw the error in my code and have written it correctly... Thank you once again.